# How to bind an ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> to a Label with a Formatter?

Tags: javafx, binding, formatter

I have an `ObservableList<Items> items` and can calculate the sum of the items prices (`BigDecimal`)  and bind the result to a labels text property in the following way:

```
 totalSumLabel.textProperty().bind(
                Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> items.stream()
                                .map(item -> item.getPrice())
                                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add),
                        items)
                .asString("%.2f €"));
```

But now i would like to use a formatter (`DecimalFormat`) instead of the `asString("%.2f €")` method to be more flexible and i don't know how to realize that. It would be nice if someone could show how to implement the binding with a formatter (without the use of a listener when possible). Thank you.

Comment: Don't believe there's anything in `Bindings` or `ObjectExpression` which directly provides what you want. You could use `Bindings.createStringBinding(...)`, which depends on the result of your `Bindings.createObjectBinding(...)` call, to implement what you want. Embedding this all into one line of code probably won't be very readable, however; consider breaking it up into multiple lines (i.e. using intermediate variables) and/or creating a helper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Slaw's comment i was able to figure out the following working solution:

```
ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> totalSumObjectBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
                                items.stream()
                                        .map(item -> item.getPrice())
                                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add),
                        items);

DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());

StringBinding totalSumStringBinding = Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
            formatter.format(totalSumObjectBinding.getValue()), totalSumObjectBinding);

totalSumLabel.textProperty().bind(totalSumStringBinding);
```

If there is an even more eloquent way, please let me know.